# Adding close operation to a JButton

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to make a JButton prompt the user to save the contents in a JTextArea before closing the program. So far, I have some code for the close operation for my button, but even that doesn't seem to work... nothing happens when I click it:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

  if(event.getSource() == this.Quit)
        this.dispose();
....
```

the rest are more else/if/try statements for other buttons.

I set my class to extend JFrame and implement ActionListener, so my entire program is in one class... probably not a very neat way to code, but I'm finding it easier to stick everything here for now before I distribute some functions into other classes.

Basically, nothing happens, and I don't know how to add the save prompt along with closing it afterwards. Any help would be great!

Comment: This `actionPerformed` is from which component? Your frame or button? Hard to provide help with so few details.

Comment: 1) *"I set my class to extend JFrame and implement ActionListener, so my entire program is in one class..."*  I can create code in one *source file* that neither extends frame nor requires it to implement action listener.  Consider adding an anonymous inner action for each button. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to tie this into a prompt to save before closing?

See [Closing an Application](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/).

Note: you can also add the ExitAction to your JButton. Then when you click on the button it will initiate the closing of the window.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MyClass.this.setVisible(false);
```

Also for a hard application exit do:

```
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: The short code provided doesn't show enough to figure out where the call to `this.dispose` is made. I removed my last comment cause the code you provided might actually work correctly.

Comment: Thanks! System.exit(0); worked while the first one didn't for some reason, but at least it's closing the application. Is there any way to tie this into a prompt to save before closing? It's a notepad program, so I'd like it to save what is in a JTextArea to a file.

Answer (score 0):

A more easy way to do what you want is this:

```
class MyClass extends JFrame{
    public MyClass(){
        JButton myButton;
        //... etc
        myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                 MyClass.this.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
    }
}
```